# как установить связь между двумя независимыми блоками

Tags: javascript

есть такой html

```
 <div id="basket_hidden_info">
     <div class="basket_container">    
        <div class="basket_border" id="product1">            
            <div class="selected_product_image">
                <img src="image.jpg" />                           
            </div>                 
            <div class="basket_close" id="close_product1">
                <img src="images/menu/bt_close_login_form.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="">            
                <div class="basket_description"> product description </div>
            </div>                           
        </div> 
       2 блок 
       3 блок     
      ...
```

и есть второй независимый контейнер

```
<div id="basket_hidden_info">
          <table class="table_basket_products" >
             <tr>
                 <td class="basket_picture"> 
                    <img src="image.jpg" />
                 </td>                            
             </tr>
         </table>
2 блок 
3 блок 
...
```

и есть ф-я которая по клику удаляет выбранный блок из 1 контейнера

js

```
close = document.getElementsByClassName('basket_close');
    function closed(e){                  
            var main = e.target.parentNode.parentNode;       
            main.remove();       
        }  
        for (var i=0;i<close.length;i++){eventsObj.addEvent(close[i],'click', closed);}
```

вопрос в том, как связать первый блок из первого контейнера с первым блоком из второго контейнера и т.д что бы обработчик события влиял на эти два связанных блока в разных контейнерах

Answer (score 2):

Логично в едином месте держать данные о наборе/состоянии корзины (назовём его `basket_store` – может быть просто массив). Оттуда обновлять отображение – в двух div'ах в данном случае.

По мышиному событию клика по "удалить" – ничего не делать непосредственно с дивом/товаром, где это нажали, а удалить товар из `basket_store` – он «хозяин» всех отображений. Изменение `basket_store`, в свою очередь, должно вызвать перерисовку обоих div'ов.

Я бы попробовал для этих корзин прикрутить [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/) – задача простая, как раз, чтобы попробовать!

Comment: боюсь для меня слишком сложно, хотелось бы просто на js

Answer (score 1):

решил таким способом, кому интересно

```
function closed(e){                  
    var main = e.target.parentNode.parentNode;                
    first = document.getElementsByClassName('basket_border');                 
    second = document.getElementsByClassName('table_basket_products');        
    for (var i = 0; i<first.length;i++){
        if (main == first[i] ){           
        first[i].remove();
        second[i].remove();            
        }                      
    }            
}
```